# функция eval() считает ли она cos sin tg ctg

Tags: python, eval

Всем привет, пишу код инженерного калькулятора и нигде не могу найти инфу функция eval() считает ли она cos sin tg ctg? Если да то какое написано должно быть, если нет то как можно заменить чтобы считала?

Answer (score 3):

```
import math
print(eval("math.cos(math.pi/4)"))
```

или

```
from math import cos, pi
print(eval("cos(pi/4)"))
```

Просто говоря, `eval` использует те функции, которые вы можете применить и в вашем коде в том же месте.

Comment: а если я хочу узнать косинус от числа, то как нужно прописывать?

Comment: В этом примере используется число. Pi/4 - это число. Если вам нужно число, введённое пользователем, то вставьте его в нужное место строки для eval. Вообще говоря, использование eval, если вы не собираетесь вводить длинные выражения, не оправдано

Comment: Да и вообще "eval is evil", использовать его нужно осторожно.